# JQuery Accordion issue due to CMS output

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, content-management-system, accordion

I am having an issue due to the way my CMS I am using outputs navigational items. I have asked this question before and have received a solution that should work however due to JS not being my strong point I don't get it. A short background. My CMS outputs a menu item like:

```
<ul id="amenu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li><span class="currentbranch0">
        <a href="">Content</a></span>
        <ul class="multilevel-linkul-0" title="">
            <li><a href="">Content 2</a></li>
            <li><span class="currentbranch1"><a href="">Content 3</a></span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Wheres the issue? Well the CMS outputs the active selector class in a span, as well as incrementing it depending on the level, currentbranchN as can be seen from the code.

I have received help on here on another thread, and we have got to this point:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#amenu > li > a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).closest("span[class*='currentbranch']").attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('#amenu li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#amenu li a').closest("span[class*='currentbranch']").removeClass('active');
      $(this).closest("span[class*='currentbranch']").addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

But it just doesn't work as an accordion, please see JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/EKe2R/5/. I reckon I am close to getting it working, but as my JS skills are basic at best I cannot seem to get my head around it. I basically need the menu to expand (if a second level item is selected) and highlight the active object, currentbranch1, using the CMS outputted nav items.

Thanks! :)

Nick

Edit: Just to add to this, the main issue the Accordion does not work is that even for second level the CMS outputs for the first level also, causing the code to fail

```
<span class="currentbranch0"></span>
```

EDIT::

I am going to try hard coding the thing to slide down, here is the code I have tryed and its failed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#amenu > li > a,#amenu > li > span > a').click(function(){
      //alert($(this).closest("span[class='currentbranch0']").attr('class'));
    if ($(this).closest("span[class='currentbranch0']").attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('#amenu li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).parents('li').children('ul').slideDown();
      $('#amenu li a').closest("span[class='currentbranch0']").removeClass('active');
      $(this).closest("span[class='currentbranch0']").addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GgKyV/1/ Fiddle here

Also how do I get the fiddle to automatically open the accortion is the link is selected, The first level lis will be actual links to web content, not dummys

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting the anchor link which is the first child of li element

```
$('#amenu > li > a')
```

but in your HTML the anchor link is the second child

```
<li><span class="currentbranch1"><a href="">Content 3</a></span></li>
```

Also the active class cannot be checked by your method but you can check it by hasClass function.

See if this fiddle works for you

http://jsfiddle.net/fdcd6/1/

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting below result. please check below link.

http://jsfiddle.net/EKe2R/11/

only js code changed.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#amenu > li > a,#amenu > li > span > a').click(function(){
          //alert($(this).closest("span[class*='currentbranch']").attr('class'));
        if ($(this).closest("span[class*='currentbranch']").attr('class') != 'active'){
          $('#amenu li ul').slideUp();
          $(this).parents('li').children('ul').slideDown();
          $('#amenu li a').closest("span[class*='currentbranch']").removeClass('active');
          $(this).closest("span[class*='currentbranch']").addClass('active');
        }
      });
});
```

Comment: I think were getting somewhere now :) . How do I make the accordion expand once the currentbranch0 class is active? The code above won't work on the CMS (accordion slides up straight after press). I reckon this is due to the CMS making the span active? Even if it was hard coding the opening of the currentbranch0 branch if sselected it would be great :)

Comment: Would the fact that I am using .click( ) be my issue here? I need the active one to open on load, in fact it wont be opening on click, as clicking will send the user to another page, where it should open

Comment: i think you should add your content cms based jsfiddle in question. it is very difficult to analyze what you want from the above comment.

Comment: Cheers User, I cleared up some points on my new thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135822/jquery-hide-uls-and-only-expand-once-particular-class-set-bit-like-an-accordion :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this...

```
  $('.currentbranch0').on('click', function(){
       $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
  });
```

And see this [jSfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EKe2R/14/)